# What is the generalized formula for the sum of the series represented by $\sum_{i=0}^ {\log_2 (n)-1} (2^i\cdot i)$?

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

I am trying to find out the generalized formula for the sum of this series, which looks like: $$2^0 \cdot 0 + 2^1 \cdot 1 + 2^2 \cdot 2 + \dots + 2^{\log_2(n)-1} \cdot (\log_2(n)-1)$$ which I have represented as $$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2(n)-1} (2^i\cdot i)$$ where $n=2^m, m>0$.

Could you somebody help me out with a solution for this?

Comment: $\log(n-1)$ is not an integer, do you mean sum to an integer close to $\log(n-1)$ or something like that.

Comment: Could you please use mathjax for math formatting because it is a bit difficult to understand what you actually mean to ask.  Refer the given link for mathjax formatting. 
      https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Manthanein: Sure i will refer to it and correct it. Thanks

Comment: @achillehui: where n is power of 2. ie $2^m$ where m is any positive integer

Answer (score 2):

The sum is essentially $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} k z^k$ evaluated at $z = 2$. 
Notice

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} k z^k =  \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right) z^k
= \left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} z^k
= \left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)\frac{1-z^m}{1-z}
= \frac{-mz^m}{1-z} + \frac{z(1-z^m)}{(1-z)^2}
$$
The sum at hand equals to
$$\frac{-m2^m}{1-2} + \frac{2(1-2^m)}{(1-2)^2} = m 2^m - 2(2^m - 1) = (m-2)2^m + 2$$

Answer (score 0):

First, consider the series 
$ S = 2^0 \cdot 0 + 2^1 \cdot 1 + 2^2 \cdot 2 + . . . + 2^{m-1} \cdot (m-1)$

Then, 
 $ 2 \cdot S = 2^1 \cdot 0 + 2^2 \cdot 1 + 2^3 \cdot 2 + . . . + 2^{m-1} \cdot (m-2) + 2^m \cdot (m-1) $

$ S = 2\cdot S - S = (m-1) \cdot 2^{m} - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} 2^k.$

But $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} 2^k $ is a geometric progression, which evaluates to $2^m - 2.$

$S = (m-1) \cdot 2^m - (2^m - 2)$

$S = 2^m \cdot (m-2) +2 $

Since $n = 2^m$, 
$ S = n \cdot (log_2{n} - 2) + 2$.